# Does the red flag scene in Ozark make any sense?

Tags: realism, ozark

In Ozark episode S3:E4 Boss Fight, Marty Byrde fixes a red flag (frozen funds) on a Panamanian bank account. He says:

> [image: Marty Byrde fixes red flag]
>
> You have a red flag on a Panamanian deposit account. That happens. All you have to do is you have to clone the frozen assets, using a pre-authorized access code. And then, you have to redirect the deposit history in order to hide the inter-bank transfer. You change the passcode twice so that you circumvent the automated security checks. And then you're done.

I would say removing a red flag from a bank account can only be done manually by a bank or government employee and you cannot simply hide inter-bank transfers. To me this whole quote sounds like [Hollywood hacking](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/HollywoodHacking). But, I don't know much about international banking.

Does anything in this quote make sense?

Comment: Didn't see this episode. But something not making sense in Ozark wouldn't surprise me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a former auditor, no this is pure Hollywood nonsense. We conduct specific tests to investigate interbank transfers to catch kiting, fraudulent entries, or in general discrepancies between bank records and internal accounting records. The line in particular about "re-directing the deposit history" makes no sense in this context.